# django Unhandled Exception after MySQL upgrade

Tags: python, mysql, django

My client's app was running fine yesterday but gives an Unhandled Exception today. I called Bluehost (the hosting provider) and eventually found that they upgraded MySQL today. This after seeing connection errors in my log.

```
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

My theory is that Django is now attempting to connect with an outdated driver. I tried

```
pip install MySQL-python --upgrade
```

but there was no effect.

I would be grateful for any tips on how to get Django connecting to MySQL again, and also how to log more useful information on the Unhandled Exception.

Thanks!

- EDITED TO ADD: Django is running using FastCGI on an Apache server.

Additionally, the Django log no longer gives any errors or anything at all. Attempts to access the web site or the web services defined for the site cause no activity in the log. But it appears the processes are still running.

I am not root on these servers and unfortunately cannot restart Apache or FCGI.

Comment: Do you really need a local socket connection, why not using TCP/IP to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Hello Mr. Ivan,
Thanks for the comment. Perhaps your suggested method is better; I'm still fairly new at Django. I added the 127.0.0.1 to the HOST parameter in settings.py but there is no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pressing Bluehost tech support on the issue, it turned out that the MySQL upgrade was a very minor one. So my theory that the Python driver to MySQL was bad turned out to be incorrect. (Especially since I ran upgrade on it through pip to no effect).

Ultimately, I killed the python processes and that caused them to be automatically restarted by the system, with everything restored to normal.